# Entity Framework OfType()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's assume I have a parent entity "Firm" and a handful of child entities that inherit from Firm.  Assuming the children are named "RedFirm", "GreenFirm", and "BlueFirm", what is the proper way to query the Firm collection if I want to retrieve only RedFirm and GreenFirm instances?

I know I can do `context.Firms.OfType(RedFirm)`, but that only returns the RedFirm instances.  Is there anyway to pass a collection of types into OfType or something similar to that?  I suppose this can be done through a union but I would think that would be less efficient.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
context.Firms.Where(x => x is RedFirm || x is GreenFirm);
```

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like:

```
context.Firms.Where(item => (!(item is BlueFirm)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
context.Firm.OfType<RedFirm>()./Rest of the query/
```

This is the way to user OfType